# iOS Alternative Look and Feel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, themes, look-and-feel

When I was first learning Java, the JGoodies Look 'n' Feel seemed great, and the same thing is available for WPF in the form of WPF Themes and WPF Futures. Are the any such libraries for iOS with which I can skin my app? I seem to get iOS screenshots with anything I search for, but I'm looking for things like UITableView header backgrounds or tab bar backgrounds. Apps always seem more professional when they have nicer, custom control backgrounds.

Comment: Without breaking NDA, I suggest you read some of the change notes on UIKit in iOS 5.0.  I believe you might find what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of developers create their own custom table cell interfaces in Interface Builder and load those as the cells for a Table View. This gives you many options and is fairly straightforward, and you can get something much more interesting than the stock table view appearances.

Comment: There look to be some nice features coming. I always try to avoid getting disappointed during betas though.